# TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "ProductCategory" in Typeorm @Tree Entity

Tags: node.js, typeorm, circular-dependency, medusajs

I have an Entity in TypeORM that defines a Tree like table in postgres:

```
import { generateEntityId } from "../utils/generate-entity-id"
import { BaseEntity } from "../interfaces/models/base-entity"
import { kebabCase } from "lodash"
import { Product } from "."
import {
  BeforeInsert,
  Column,
  Entity,
  Index,
  JoinColumn,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  Tree,
  TreeChildren,
  TreeParent,
} from "typeorm"

@Entity()
@Tree("materialized-path")
@Index(["parent_category_id", "rank"], { unique: true })
export class ProductCategory extends BaseEntity {
  static productCategoryProductJoinTable = "product_category_product"
  static treeRelations = ["parent_category", "category_children"]


  @Index({ unique: true })
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  handle: string

  @TreeParent()
  @JoinColumn({ name: "parent_category_id" })
  parent_category: ProductCategory | null

  // Typeorm also keeps track of the category's parent at all times.
  @Column()
  parent_category_id: string | null

  @TreeChildren({ cascade: true })
  category_children: ProductCategory[]

  @ManyToMany(() => Product, { cascade: ["remove", "soft-remove"] })
  @JoinTable({
    name: ProductCategory.productCategoryProductJoinTable,
    joinColumn: {
      name: "product_category_id",
      referencedColumnName: "id",
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: "product_id",
      referencedColumnName: "id",
    },
  })
  products: Product[]

  @BeforeInsert()
  private beforeInsert(): void {
    this.id = generateEntityId(this.id, "pcat")

    if (!this.handle) {
      this.handle = kebabCase(this.name)
    }
  }
}
```

Now I import this `ProductCategory` into my own file to extend it like so:

```
import {
  ProductCategory as MedusaProductCategory,
} from "@medusajs/medusa";
import {

  Column,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
@Tree("materialized-path")
export class ProductCategory extends MedusaProductCategory {
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  breadcrumb_name: string;
```

I am aliasing is and then I extend the alias by 1 column.

In a next step I want to use my custom ProductCategory class and extend an existing TypeORM Repository like so:

```
import { ProductCategory } from "../models/product-category";
import { dataSource } from "@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/database";
import {
  // alias the core repository to not cause a naming conflict
  ProductCategoryRepository as MedusaProductCategoryRepository,
} from "@medusajs/medusa/dist/repositories/product-category";

export const ProductCategoryRepository = dataSource
  .getTreeRepository(ProductCategory)
  .extend({
    // it is important to spread the existing repository here.
    // Otherwise you will end up losing core properties.
    // you also update the target to the extended entity
    ...Object.assign(MedusaProductCategoryRepository, {
      target: ProductCategory,
    }),
    // you can add other customizations as well...
  });

export default ProductCategoryRepository;
```

As you can see I Import my Custom ProductCategory and try to extend the existing ProductCategoryRepository that is already provided by Medusa.

The big problem is now: Whenever I build and run this and try to interact with the database, TypeORM throws this error:

```
error:   Cyclic dependency: "ProductCategory"
TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "ProductCategory"
    at visit (my_server/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:147:23)
    at visit (my_server/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:164:21)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.toposort (my_server/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:143:17)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (my_server/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:53:45)
    at SubjectExecutor.execute (my_server/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:91:108)
    at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (my_server/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:148:36)
```

I have been trying for hours now but I cannot find the issue.
My estimate is that I need to somehow extend the Entity with the @Tree decorators as well.

Thank you so much for whoever can answer this and everyone else

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove `@Entity()` and `@Tree("materialized-path")` decorators from your custom `ProductCategory` class?